# Refresh Component on route parameter change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why the component doesn't update the props when changing the route param?

Trying to use `setState` inside `componentWillReceiveProps` but it doesn't even fire?

```
export default class HomePage extends React.PureComponent {
  movies = require('../../movieList.json');
  state = {
    match: this.props.match,
    id: null
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(np) {
    if(np.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
      console.log('UPDATING PROPS')
      this.setState({ match: np.match })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;

    const movie = this.movies[match.params.id || movieOrder[0]];
    const nextMovie = getNextMovie(match.params.id || movieOrder[0]);
    const prevMovie = getPrevMovie(match.params.id || movieOrder[0]);
    return (
      <>
        <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
        <Link to={nextMovie}>Next</Link>
        <Link to={prevMovie}>Prev</Link>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

`nextMovie` and `prevMovie` get the id which should be set inside link. Unfortunatelly it sets only during 1st render. When clicked I can see the url change, but no updates are fired

Here is the component holding the switch

````
export default class App extends React.PureComponent {

  state = {
    isLoading: true,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    PreloaderService.preload('core').then(() => {
      console.log('LOADED ALL');
      console.log('PRELOADER SERVICE', PreloaderService);
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      console.log('Preloader assets', PreloaderService.getAsset('dog-video'))
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;

    if(isLoading) {
      return(
        <div>
          is loading
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {/* <Background /> */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/:id" component={props => <HomePage {...props} />} />
          <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
        <GlobalStyle />
      </div>
    );
  }

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working with my [codesandbox recreation](https://codesandbox.io/s/refresh-component-on-route-parameter-change-9tnvg).

I had to improvise a bit with the missing code:

What's the value of `movieOrder[0]`? Is `0` a valid value for `match.params.id`?

How do `getNextMovie` and `prevMovie` look like?

Also, you're not using the `Home` component's state in your `render` logic, so I think, it should render the correct movie even without them.

Comment: The thing i was missing was wrapping Switch inside BrowserRouter

Answer (score 0):

There are several things off here. `componentWillReceiveProps` is considered unsafe and is [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops). Try using `componentDidUpdate` [instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). Also your class component needs a `constructor`. As it is now `state` is defined as a static variable.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    match: this.props.match,
    id: null
  }
}

componentDidUpdate(np) {
  if(np.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
    console.log('UPDATING PROPS')
    this.setState({ match: np.match })
  }
}
```

Last, double check to make sure your logic is correct. Right now the `Next` and `Prev` buttons link to the same thing:

```
const nextMovie = getNextMovie(match.params.id || movieOrder[0]);
const prevMovie = getPrevMovie(match.params.id || movieOrder[0]);

<Link to={nextMovie}>Next</Link>
<Link to={prevMovie}>Prev</Link>
```

As an alternative, if you want to stick with `componentWillReceiveProps` you need to unbind the current movie, and rebind it with a new one. Here is a [code example](https://github.com/insin/react-hn/blob/master/src/UserProfile.js) doing the exact same thing with users.

Comment: constructor is not necessary - declaring state the way i do is alternative syntax